# Using QGIS to create XYZ .png tiles on EC2

Tags: qgis, postgis, tiles, amazon-ec2

I have set up a PostgreSQL/PostGIS DB on an EC2 that contains my .osm data. I populated it with osm2pgsql. Now, I can create tiles on my local machine using the QGIS "Generate XYZ Tiles (Directory)" tool. However, it is a rather tedious process. For example, I have four layers in the current map layer I'm creating and they have been styled accordingly (it is fairly simple). Is there a way to set up and tell a headless (EC2) process these settings? I had quite a bit of compiling from source to even set up PostGIS and osm2pgsql on the EC2 so I've grown quite weary.

Answer (score 0):

I figured I can rather easily use the docker image from `qgis/qgis`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).